# SSAS Tabular deleting Partitions breaks Model

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, ssas-tabular

I have a few fact tables in my model, each with a couple dozen dated partitions, each with around 3 million rows

When I delete any of these partitions, either through SSMS (Tables -> Partitions -> Delete), or by TMSL:

```
{
              "delete": {
                "object": {
                 "database": "XXXX",
                 "table": "MYTABLE",
                 "partition": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                }
              }
            }
```

It deletes successfully, but then when I go to browse the Model through Excel, I get:

> "The expression referenced a relationship between 'MYTABLE'[COBId] and 'Date'[COBId], which does not hold any data because it needs to be recalculated"

I have confirmed the measures are accessible before deleting the partition (any partition) and is broken immediately afterwards

Strangely, if I then process Default on *any* one partition in the affected table, then it all works again

Can anyone shed light on this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a partition requires you run a Process Recalc on the Database (or a Process Default which includes a recalc). Basically deleting a partition has invalidated the some relationships, calculated columns and hierarchies so they need to be rebuilt.